# Why is a PDO INSERT failing in my loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am brand new to programming and am trying to build a website for my sister as a first project.  It is a fairly simple photo gallery.

One thing I am trying to do right now is loop through an entire directory sitting on my computer(I know this will have to be changed when i put this on a webserver) and updating the image paths into MySQL.  I have setup a good connection to the database, but am encountering problems with my loop.

```
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {  
    $values[] = $file;
 };

 while (list($var, $val) = each($values)){
    $query = ("INSERT INTO emilys_photos.images (path, who_update) VALUES ($val, 'morgan')");
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

 }
```

I know this is breaking because of my while loop, but I am having trouble debugging it, and figuring out where it is breaking at.  I am unaware how to do a bulk INSERT as well, I've read plenty of stack overflow answers and have tried what they put down using implode but have not got any of those to work either.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Add some [error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and you'll have your answer.

Comment: why not use foreach instaed of while?

Comment: Why don't you describe `how` it is breaking....

Comment: Your INSERT statement appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. The  PDO interface conveniently supports bind placeholders in prepared statements.

Comment: The brackets here `$query = (" ... ")` are unnecessary - it is just a string, so I'd recommend removing them.

Comment: Jay Blanchard, how can i use PDOException for error handling?  I am having a trouble debugging MySQL statements as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I recommend using parameter binding, as @spencer7595 says. Change your code to this:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO emilys_photos.images
        (path, who_update)
        VALUES (:path, 'morgan')
";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':path' => $val, ]);
```

I've done a bit of string wrapping too - both PHP and SQL databases are fine with this, and is makes things *so* much more readable.